# pandas_ta working with windows and not with mac

Tags: windows, macos, pandas-ta

I have anaconda installed on my windows machine and my mac, when I tried running a code of pandas-ta all strategy on windows its giving me the answer but the same notebook when I run it on mac its giving me an error.

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'append'

The version of pandas-ta is same in both the computers (0.3.14b0). Any help is highly appreciated

[on mac machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OAkh.png)

[on mac machine 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qvyf.png)

[on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLYyv.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df.ta.strategy(ta.AllStrategy) is deprecated. And uses  series append function which is deprecated. Use df.ta.study(ta.AllStudy) instead.